# How can i get images from the hard disk resize the images and add them to a list<image> fast?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, performance

I'm doing now

```
imageslist = new List<Image>();
            foreach (string myFile in
                      Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myFile);
                imageslist.Add(bmp);
            }
```

But the `foreach` is very slow.
And i have this method to resize the images i want to resize them before adding them to the list

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
        {
            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            return destImage;
        }
```

In the end i want to have in the `List<Image> imageslist` all the images in size of 100,100 resolution and the images are now 24 bit depth should i try to change it also or 24 bit is fine ?

Answer (score 1):

I have two improvements:

1. Use *Directory.EnumerateFiles* instead of *Directory.GetFiles*, you will not have to wait until all results will be returned, it will be lazy evaluated
2. Run the resizing in parallel (in my example below using *AsParallel* extension method)

```
var imageslist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(path => new Bitmap(path))
    .Select(bmp => ResizeImage(bmp, 100, 100))
    .ToList();
```

Remember to verify the speed of the parallel solution because only after comparing it with non-parallel solution (run the code without *AsParallel*) you will be sure that it improves performance in your case.